# Anne Pro 2 Bluetooth keyboard sometimes disconnects with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard

I received an anne pro 2 keyboard recently to replace my main keyboard, but this keyboard stops sending data to my Ubuntu sometimes and I have to reconnect it to be able to work with it again.

This problem occurs when I try to reduce or increase the backlight in Ubuntu and obinskit app is closed, Otherwise it works fine.

Sometimes it sends the last pressed key multiple times and then stops working.

I tried to find fix it by upgrading the firmware to the latest version (both release and alpha) but it didn't work.

I Found a fix for it by downgrading to 1.12.8 but this version of firmware does not include all I need.

Is there any other fix for this problem? Like being able to run the obinskit app in the background somehow?

Comment: Any update on trying out the solution? I'm thinking of getting an annepro2 myself

Comment: @Tian nope, I contacted support but the solution didn't help, I downgraded the firmware and its working fine now on both windows and ubuntu,

Comment: I have the same problem. I noticed that this occurs when some other devices are connected to my bluetooth too. If the keyboard its the only connected to my computer it's fine. Did you fix it?

Comment: @ctaglia Nope, I gave up using the blutooth afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I am using ANNE PRO2 as the latest firmware in the same environment. It works fine.

```
App Processor 2.19
Light Processor 2.16
BT Processor 2.03
```

Why not try making a Bluetooth connection again?

Ubuntu 20 asks for a PIN when connecting Bluetooth. However, the Bluetooth connection method of ANNE PRO2 does not provide a PIN, so the connection fails. So, you need to try pairing without a PIN number to connect successfully.

```
$ bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# power on
...
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
...
[bluetooth]# pairable on
...
[bluetooth]# agent NoInputNoOutput
...
[bluetooth]# default-agent
...
[bluetooth]# pair XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Where `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` is to be replaced with the correct hardware address of the keyboard. To find this address, you can use:

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
```

The output will show addresses for available devices.

Comment: I tried the bluetooth method, it connects and there is no problem in the first few minutes but after a while it glitchs again (sending the key and disconnecting)